# Draw multiple curves on one picture via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

this is my first time using this wonderful website. and I've already trapped in this question for a long time. I hope there is someone's help.
Question Details: I can't Draw multiple curves on one picture via matplotlib. I've tried using scatter rather than plot, but it still didn't work. until now, running this program can only show one curve which is green made from last plot statement. and I debug for many times, but i gotta nothing improved.my desired expectation is to have all six curves shown in one picture with corresponding colors, appreciate your help.Here is my code:

```
from scipy.special import comb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# setting paraments
N = 100000
x = range(501)
a = range(5,11)

# define a function to traverse all x and find M
def get_P_A(a_):
    M_results = []
    for x_ in x:
        a1 = 1
        sum_P = 0.0
        while (a1 <= a_):
            P_A = comb(x_, a1) * comb(N - x_, 5 - a1) / comb(N, 5)
            M = 1 * (1 - P_A) * N / a_ + (a_ + 1) * P_A * N / a_
            sum_P += M
            a1 += 1
        M_results.append(sum_P)
    return M_results

# traverse all a and store the result in M_total_results
M_total_results = [get_P_A(a_) for a_ in a]

# visualize calculation results
plt.plot(x,M_total_results[0],color='red',linewidth=3,linestyle='--')  #When M=5, use the red line to show the result

plt.plot(x,M_total_results[1],color='blue',linewidth=3,linestyle='--')  #When M=6, use the blue line to show the result

plt.plot(x,M_total_results[2],color='yellow',linewidth=3,linestyle='--')  #When M=7, use the yellow line to show the result
 
plt.plot(x,M_total_results[3],color='cyan',linewidth=3,linestyle='--')  #When M=8, use the cyan line to show the result
 
plt.plot(x,M_total_results[4],color='black',linewidth=3,linestyle='--')  #When M=9, use the black line to show the result

plt.plot(x,M_total_results[5],color='green',linewidth=3,linestyle='--')  #When M=10, use the green line to show the result

# add corresponding labels to the chart
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']=['SimHei']
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
plt.title("Distribution of the number of mixed samples under different positive samples",size=24)
plt.xlabel("number of positive samples/个",size=14)
plt.ylabel("M",size=14)
plt.tick_params(axis='both',size=14)
plt.grid(alpha=0.8,linestyle=':')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you are trying to calculate?  You should really test with smaller values for N.  Note that  dividing by `comb(N, 5)` (which is `8.33e+22`) makes the values almost zero.  You are hitting accuracy problems due to the size of the numbers.

Comment: Note that in `comb(N - x_, 5 - a1)` is zero for the highest `a1`, because then `5 - a1` is negative. This makes all curves equal.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I was only looking for grammar problems, but that was a content problem. hhh, that's so awkward

Comment: Well, the only fundamental problem with your code is that the curves overlap too much. You really should first tackle the content. To test the grammar, just try with two curves and small numbers. Also note that your formula for `M` simplifies to `N*(P_A + 1/a_)` (which reduces the precision problems a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Your plotting code is fine. If you print the rows of M_total_results, you will find the curves are overlapping.
You can also check it by adjusting the alpha of the bottom curves.

Comment: Thank you for your help. but when I printed the rows of M_total_results, I could find there were some points having explicit differences. and when I enlarged the graph and adjust the alpha, i still couldn't find other lines. maybe it isn't just an overlapping problem?

Comment: The difference might still be too small relative to the scale of the chart. To adjust alpha, try lower the green line's alpha to 0.1, you will find the line is mostly black; also adjusting the black line alpha to 0.1; the line is now mostly cyan.